# Multivariable limit which should be simple !

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to calculate the following limit WITHOUT using spherical coordinates?

$$
\lim _{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0) } \frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{x^2+y^2+z^2} 
$$
?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why should the limit be simple? (especially without using spherical coordinates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$. If $(x,y,z)$ is close enough to $(0,0,0)$ but not equal to it, then $|x^3|\le \epsilon x^2$, with similar inequalities for $|y^3|$ and $|z^3|$. It follows that
$$\frac{|x^3+y^3+z^3|}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\le \frac{|x^3|+|y^3|+|z^3|}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\le \frac{\epsilon (x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$

Comment: So the limit is zero?

Comment: Yes it is, the answer above is a proof of that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^2 \le x^2+y^2+z^2$, we have $|x| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, and similarly for $|y|$ and $|z|$. This gives
$$
\left|\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|
\le \frac{|x|^3+|y|^3+|z|^3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
\le \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
.
$$
Can you take it from there?